# In how many ways can you create a paragraph in LaTeX?

Tags: paragraphs

How many ways are there to indicate the beginning of a new paragraph in LaTeX? Only way I know of is the double linebreak.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Neither an empty line nor a `\par` token indicate the beginning of a new paragraph; they end an active paragraph and switch to unrestricted vertical mode (if the processor has been in unrestricted horizontal mode so far). To begin a new paragraph, either `\indent`, `\noindent` or a horizontal command has to be used—i.e., a command that forces TeX to switch to (unrestricted) horizontal mode. Well known horizontal commands are the character-insertion commands such as `a`, and `\unhbox`. The full list of horizontal commands is given by §6.2 of TeX by Topic.

Comment: @Phillip: The question is about LaTeX and I guess, since the questioner referred to a blank line, he would like to end a paragraph and to start a new one, in LaTeX. Of course your tips are interesting!

Answer (score 16):

Phillip has given a great explanation how paragraphs can be started. Since you question means alternatives to a double line break, which actually doesn't start a paragraph but it ends one, I assume your intention is how to create a paragraph break, i.e. how to end a paragraph.

You could use the command `\par` instead of two consecutive linebreaks, i.e. instead of an empty line in your source code.

Another possibility is `\endgraf`, since `latex.ltx` defines

```
\let\endgraf=\par
```

Then, there's `^^M` (if active, such as done by `\obeylines`) and `\@@par`. Packages could define further aliases and even modify paragraph commands (yes, there's also `\@par`).

Just scan `latex.ltx` or `source2e` to find such commands.

I would recommend to use blank lines or `\par`, but not other internal commands or shortcuts, to keep your code readable.

Comment: Stefan This post needs correction, all the commands you mentioned end a paragraph and not start a new one, even if they appear so.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Thanks, I clarified the intention of the answer, as the question is a bit ambiguous since it speaks about double line breaks.

Answer (score 6):

An empty line and `\par` have been already mentioned, but there is more. Quoting *The TeXbook*, p. 86:

> A paragraph also ends when you type
>   certain things that are incompatible
>   with horizontal mode. For example, the
>   command `\vskip 1in` on line 16 of
>   Chapter 6's story file was enough to
>   terminate the paragraph about
>   `...beautiful documents.`; no `\par` was
>   necessary, since `\vskip` introduced
>   vertical glue that couldn't belong to
>   the paragraph.

Comment: It is worth noting, though, that LaTeX's `\vspace` is different, in that it wraps a `\vskip` in a `\vadjust` if encountered in horizontal mode, so that horizontal mode is not interrupted, and the space is added between the current line and the next one